# Javascript OOP - accessing the inherited property or function from a closure within a subclass

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

I am using the javascript inheritance helper provided here: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

I have the following code, and I have problem accessing the inherited property or function from a closure within a subclass as illustrated below. I am new to OOP javascript code and I appreciate your advice. I suppose within the closure, the context changes to JQuery (this variable) hence the problem. I appreciate your comments.

Thanks,
-A

PS - Using JQuery 1.5

```
     var Users = Class.extend({
                init: function(names){this.names = names;}
            });
            var HomeUsers = Users.extend({
                work:function(){ 
//                alert(this.names.length); // PRINTS A 
//                var names = this.names;  // If I make a local alias it works
                    $.map([1,2,3],function(){
                        var newName = this.names.length; //error this.names is not defined.
                        alert(newName); 
                    });

                }
            });

var users = new HomeUsers(["A"]);
users.work();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in the inner function

```
    function(){
        var newName = this.names.length;
        alert(newName); 
    }
```

is not the same as `this` in the outer function.

```
work: function(){ 
    $.map([1,2,3],function(){
        var newName = this.names.length;
        alert(newName); 
    });
}
```

There are many ways that people work around this:

### Store a reference to outer function's `this` as another variable

```
work: function(){ 
    var that = this;
    $.map([1,2,3],function(){
        var newName = that.names.length;
        alert(newName); 
    });
}
```

As you see, `that` is being used instead of `this`.

### Use jQuery's [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
work: function(){ 
    $.map([1,2,3],$.proxy(function(){
        var newName = this.names.length;
        alert(newName); 
    }, this));
}
```

What `$.proxy` does is it creates another function that calls the function you passed in (in this case, the inner function), but explicitly set the context of the function (`this`) to the second arguments.

### Use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
work: function(){ 
    $.map([1,2,3],function(){
        var newName = this.names.length;
        alert(newName);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

It works just like jQuery's `$.proxy`, but in this one, you call the `bind` method of the function.

It isn't supported on all browsers, but there is a [JavaScript implementation of Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on MDC. You can use it.

`this` in a confusing keyword, and if you want to learn more about `this`, then look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this).

Comment: +1 for *if you want to learn more about this, then look at this.* :D (and of course for a good answer)

Answer (score 0):

The `this` variable is not like the others.  Normal variables are always available to their child scopes, but `this` is, by default, set to the global `window` object when a function is called:

```
alert(this.names); # Works; this == yourObject
$.map([1,2,3],function(){
    alert(this.names); # Doesn't work; this == window.
});
```

The documentation for [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) confirms this:

> `this` will be the global window object.

Thus, the solution is to set another variable to `this` so it will be available in the child scope:

```
var that = this;
$.map([1,2,3],function(){
    alert(that.names);
});
```

I recommend viewing Douglas Crockford's presentation [Function the Ultimate](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=crockonjs-3), in which he shows all sorts of crazy things you can do with functions and objects in JavaScript.